# Internet doesn't work when using a router

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router

I'm having trouble setting up my router at home.
The internet works fine as long as I plug in the ethernet cable directly. However, if I connect the cable to my Speedport W 700 V and then connect another ethernet cable from the router to my MacBook, the internet doesn't work anymore.
I plugged in the first cable into the DSL slot and the second cable into one of the four WAN/LAN slots.
Shouldn't the router just work as a switch?

The Speedport also has an option to use an external or internal DSL modem. Since I don't have an external one, I just use the internal. Though, I tried both option.

I reseted the router many times as well.

I want to use the router's wifi function, not really as a switch.

Answer (score 2):

The DSL socket is probably not for Ethernet.

Plug the Internet ethernet cable to a WAN port on your router.

Plug the computer Ethernet cable to a LAN port on your router.

---

A German manual (this product is mainly used in Germany) is at http://www.picturebringin.de/allgemein/BDAs/Speedport_w700v.pdf

[image]

From which I infer that your description is inconsistent. If you have an Ethernet cable being used for Ethernet which you can connect to an Ethernet port on your Computer, then there must be (the equivalent of) an external DSL modem (n.b. in some parts of the world I believe Internet access is delivered by Ethernet though perhaps only to apartments from a central area in an apartment building or in a UNiversity accomodation block or similar)

This router expect one of

- An external "modem" that presents Internet access as Ethernet.
- A telephone socket with a voice telephone circuit connected over which the Telco
  is providing ADSL service. These usually have a "splitter" to separate voice and DSL
  equipment.

**In the former case, I'd use port labelled (2) "WAN/LAN1" and choose the offboard DSL modem configuration option.**

In the latter case I'd use port labelled (1) "T-DSL"

(n.b. I don't read German very well)

Comment: most DSL connections are not done through RJ45 connections. At least in North America (I assume OP is in EU?) DSL providers connect DSL modems using RJ11 for the POTS connection, and RJ45 for the ethernet connection. I suspect EU is the same, but I don't know just yet.

Comment: @BloodyIron: Germany has a history of using ISDN extensively. Most of western Europe (inc DE) probably now uses ADSL delivered via national PSTN (POTS) outlets (i.e. the wall-socket connectors vary from country to country). ISDN cables look like Ethernet cables but it is very unlikely the OP's Macbook has a built in ISDN TA. In the UK most DSL modems are USB not RJ45/Ethernet.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick since he wants to use this DSL Modem/WifiRouter as just a Wifi ROuter, after he connects it the way you suggest, should he then use the necessary settings to make it into an Access Point?  Or is that what you meant by "offboard DSL Modem configuration"

Answer (score 0):

Alright there is some confusion here, so I'm going to be as thorough as possible.

Here is what I understand of your situation:

- Your ISP (Internet Service Provider) provides you with DSL internet service.
- Your ISP provides you with an on-site DSL modem
- You have some wierd router which I can't find english manuals for just yet
- You want to use your router (or a router) with your internet connection

**Using your router with your ISP's modem**

The simplest configuration is to use your router with your ISP's modem that they provided. I don't know if they provided you with this zaney router, but it seems too feature rich for that to be possible.

To troubleshoot it you will need to connect it in the following method

ISP > DSL Modem > WAN port on router (it looks like you have two?) > Your computers in the LAN ports

What routers do is they bridge networks. This is a step up from what switches do. Switches connect networks, however in a simplistic form they just pass traffic. In this case a router bridges your Public network access (the internet) with your Private network (if you want I can explain this further with IP addresses).

What I suspect is the problem is that your router is not getting an IP from the DSL modem. Why? Your ISP may have assigned your IP to a single MAC address. If you go into the web interface for the router, once it's connected of course, and find the WAN port you plugged your modem into, it will list IP information about that connection. If it has an IP address of 0.0.0.0 or 169.264.x.x then your ISP is not providing you with a working IP address.

You will need to call them to correct this. They can also further troubleshoot with you.

Alternatively you could purchase a more simple router, such as something by ASUS, but the router you have looks like it is rather high quality, I would work with it.

Answer (score 0):

DSL comes in as ATM traffic and is translated in to Ethernet via a modem. The modem will have a line in from the wall and an RJ45 out that is Ethernet. For most purposes, there are two distinct types of ADSL that you need to be aware of, bridged and routed. When the connection is bridged, your modem will be virtually invisible in the connection and the device that you plug into it will have a public IP. When the connection is routed, your modem will act as a router and the device that you plug into it will have a private IP.

When you want to connect a router, you need to know whether the modem is bridged or routed. If bridged, there is usually nothing more you need to do, the router will get assigned the public IP and will route connections via NAT to the internal network. When the connection is routed, you need to be more careful in your router config so that the router is using the correct default gateway and is not using the same IP as the modem. You can then do a double-nat setup (not usually recommended) or you can disable DHCP on your router and simply use it as a switch/access point. Anything that connects to it then will be routed by the modem, not the router, but you will now have more physical ports and a wireless connection to utilize.